# android custom URLSpan not working

Tags: android, urlspan

The problem is to handle my own action on click on URL span. I wrote custom URLSpan but it doesn't work.

This is my custom URLSpan:

```
public class CustomURLSpan extends android.text.style.URLSpan {
    private Command mClickAction;

    public CustomURLSpan(String url, Command clickAction) {
        super(url);
        mClickAction = clickAction;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        try {
            mClickAction.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public static void clickifyTextView(TextView tv, Command clickAction) {
        SpannableString current = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
        URLSpan[] spans =
                current.getSpans(0, current.length(), URLSpan.class);

        for (URLSpan span : spans) {
            int start = current.getSpanStart(span);
            int end = current.getSpanEnd(span);

            current.removeSpan(span);
            current.setSpan(new CustomURLSpan(span.getURL(), clickAction), start, end, 0);
        }
    }

    public interface Command {
        void execute();
    }
}
```

And here I use it:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String message = bundle.getString("message");
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    text = new TextView(activity);
    text.setText(message);

    Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
    CustomURLSpan.clickifyTextView(text, new CustomURLSpan.Command() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            //I want to do my stuff here, but not working
        }
    });
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(text);
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        ...
}
```

But if I click on url, I get the native android dialog to choose email programm. All examples I find in internet are same.

**EDIT:** According to answer from @CommonWare. I just needed:

```
...
public static void clickifyTextView(TextView tv, Command clickAction) {
    SpannableString current = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
    URLSpan[] spans =
            current.getSpans(0, current.length(), URLSpan.class);

    for (URLSpan span : spans) {
        int start = current.getSpanStart(span);
        int end = current.getSpanEnd(span);

        current.removeSpan(span);
        current.setSpan(new CustomURLSpan(span.getURL(), clickAction), start, end, 0);
        tv.setText(current); //this is what I need
    }
}

public interface Command {
    void execute();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clickifyTextView()` retrieves the text from the `TextView`, wraps it in a new `SpannableString`... then never updates the `TextView`. So `clickifyTextView()` is modifying a copy of what is in the `TextView`, which therefore does not affect the `TextView`.

Try calling `setText()` on the `TextView` after your span conversion loop in `clickifyTextView()`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried your solution. In this case I get the unclickable text, without any link at all.

Comment: @AlexanderTumanin: Make sure that you are calling `setText(current)`, not `setText(current.toString())`. If that is not it, check to see what sort of object you get back from `getText()`. If it implements `Spannable`, you do not need to create a new `SpannedString` and can just edit the contents of the `TextView` directly.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I just was wrong setting text. I made it in my dialog, but I had to make it in CustomURLSpan. You save the huge of my time!

Answer (score 4):

Set `movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod()` to your textview when using any `ClickableSpan`