# Custom URLSpan don't trigger onClick event, using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, spannable, urlspan

I have this layout:

```
<TextView
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

And this code to implement and set my customized URLSpan as the textView text

```
val urlSpan=object:URLSpan("http://10.0.2.2/feed.xml") {
    override fun onClick(widget: View?) {
        longToast("link was clicked!")
    }
}
val spannableString=SpannableString("this is a spannable link")
spannableString.setSpan(urlSpan, 10, 19, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
textView.text = spannableString
```

But the onClick event of my customized URLSpan never triggers :(
I've searched and nothing seems to work.

I've read this:
[android custom URLSpan not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088082/android-custom-urlspan-not-working)
and other threads but it was in vain.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699535/android-span-click-event

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been passing over LinkMovementMethod for hours without noticing it was the key! Thnaks for the help :)

Comment: I'm not really shure if I should delete this post... other posts I've read are "overflowed" by superfluous information. I spent more than 3 hours reading threads and googling my question, and simply ignoring the answer, just because I though the answers where responding questions that hasn't anything to do whith mine. The code I posted is "raw" and clear... it should work... but it doesn't, just becouse a key piece (LinkMovementMethod stuff) is missing. That's the answer to the question. (PD: Please excuse my english, I'm out of training)

Comment: the question linked in the top as relevant to this one, has nothing to do with it actually :D